# cocos2d-x menu item error with callback function

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have this code from 5 years ago:

```
CCMenuItemSprite* quitItem = CCMenuItemSprite::create(quitLabel,quitLabel2,quitLabel3,this,menu_selector(ClearScene::call_quitItem));
```

I'm refactoring the code and migrate to the latest cocos2d-x. The above example keeps giving me error:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type 'void (MyScene::*)()' to type 'cocos2d::SEL_SCHEDULE {aka void (cocos2d:Ref::*)(float)}'
```

I have tried using `CC_CALLBACK_n` but still not working. (similar to `HelloWorld.cpp` file:

```
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create("CloseNormal.png","CloseSelected.png",CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));
```

Comment: show your `ClearScene` class ?

Answer (score 0):

How many parameters in your `call_quitItem` method ?

**CC_CALLBACK_N**

The (N)number means how many parameters the callback function has.
`CC_CALLBACK_0` means callback function with no input parameter, such as `MyClass::doSomething()`

`CC_CALLBACK_1` means there’s only 1 input parameter. e.g., `MyClass::doSomething(int a)`

---

```
// new callbacks based on C++11
#define CC_CALLBACK_0(__selector__,__target__, ...) std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define CC_CALLBACK_1(__selector__,__target__, ...) std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define CC_CALLBACK_2(__selector__,__target__, ...) std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define CC_CALLBACK_3(__selector__,__target__, ...) std::bind(&__selector__,__target__, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```